# Toggling class of child object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to toggle the class of a selected object's child "ul" object, using the following code. When I click on one of the parents, multiple child "ul" classes toggle the class on and off instead of just the child of the selected object. Here is the code and a jsfiddle example. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jecker/kzdvbufo/)

the CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".proDocs").click(function() {
 $(this).children( "ul" ).toggleClass( "hidden" );
});
});
```

the HTML

```
<div>
 <ol type="A">
 <li class="proDocs">
Procedures
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 <ol type="a">
 <li class="proDocs">
Performance
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 <ol type="I">
 <li class="proDocs">
Validation Documents
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 <ol type="i">
 <li class="proDocs">
Evaluation
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 </li>
 <li class="proDocs">
Reports
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 </li>
 <li class="proDocs">
Certification
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 </li>
 <li class="proDocs">
Training
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 </li>
 </ol>
 </li>
 <li class="proDocs">
Other Documents
<ul class="hidden">
<li>Upload Pictures</li>
</ul>
 </li>
 </ol>
 </li>
 </ol>
 </li>
 </ol>
 </li>
 </ol>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not correct. It contains too many closes. Also any parent is also proDocs, which will be triggered by a child click.

Comment: Yep, the problem is Niels comment. the class proDocs has inside a class proDocs, so the script take the first and the second proDocs and try to do that the script does.

Comment: If you indent the code properly, you won't so easy run into such issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have multiple nested elements with the class `.proDocs` what you see here is called [**bubbling**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) when you click on a inner item it fires the function and after the function again for the upper container since have the same class.

To prevent this behavior you can use [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation), now your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".proDocs").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children("ul").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

#### [New Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kzdvbufo/7/)

---

<sub>**Note:** You can also use *return false* or *preventDefault()*
 is your choice and each one has its own particularities</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question

look the following soloution wish this help you

change your html and the formation

```
<div>
   <ol type="A">
      <li class="proDocs">
         Procedures
         <ul class="hidden">
            <li>Upload Pictures</li>
            <ol type="a">
               <li class="proDocs">
                  Performance
                  <ul class="hidden">
                     <li>Upload Pictures</li>
                     <ol type="I">
                        <li class="proDocs">
                           Validation Documents
                           <ul class="hidden">
                              <li>Upload Pictures</li>
                              <ol type="i">
                                 <li class="proDocs">
                                    Evaluation
                                    <ul class="hidden">
                                       <li>Upload Pictures</li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="proDocs">
                                    Reports
                                    <ul class="hidden">
                                       <li>Upload Pictures</li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="proDocs">
                                    Certification
                                    <ul class="hidden">
                                       <li>Upload Pictures</li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </li>
                                 <li class="proDocs">
                                    Training
                                    <ul class="hidden">
                                       <li>Upload Pictures</li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </li>
                              </ol>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="proDocs">
                           Other Documents
                           <ul class="hidden">
                              <li>Upload Pictures</li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ol>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ol>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

and then make change the following code with your javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".proDocs").click(function() {
        $(this).children( "ul:first-child" ).toggleClass( "hidden" );
      return false;
    });
});
```

wish this help you

fell free to ask me any question.